# Detectar si se instaló otra aplicación en el dispositivo

Tags: java, android

**Contexto.**
Tengo una aplicación para Android realizada con Eclipse en Java. Hace poco creé un botón en mi aplicación que da recompensas (pistas) por ver videos. Ahora tengo un botón que saca un listado de todas mis aplicaciones y me gustaría dar recompensas (pistas) por descargar mis juegos.

**Pregunta.** Me interesa saber si el usuario instaló de Google Play una aplicación determinada (aplicación desarrollada por mí).

¿Es posible detectar si han instalado una aplicación? ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Comparte el código con el que estés teniendo problemas

Answer (score 2):

Una manera que podrias hacer es abrir el Play Store tras pulsar un boton de una de las aplicaciones de la lista, y guardar en **SharedPreferences** el nombre del paquete el cual el usuario fue a instalar.
En el metodo **onResume** y **onCreate** comprobar las preferencias y ver cuales son las aplicaciones que ha ido a instalar y en funcion de cuales sean, comprobar si la aplicacion esta instalada:

```
public static boolean appInstalada(Context context, String nombrePaquete) {
try {
      context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(nombrePaquete, 0);
      return true;
    }
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Por ultimo eliminar la preferencia guardada para evitar dar la recompensa dos veces, o modificarla para saber que el usuario deberia tener la app instalada... eso ya queda a tu criterio segun que es lo que desees hacer.

Otra de las maneras que se me ocurren, es con un **BroadcastReceiver**

En el **Manifest**:

```
<application ...>
<receiver android:name=".NuevaAppDetectada" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Clase:

```
public class NuevaAppDetectada extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "NuevaAppDetectada";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Intent: " + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

Aún así, guarda el resultado en las preferencias y compruébalo en el proceso para evitar que el usuario reinstale la aplicación obteniendo recompensas continuamente y solo sean obtenidas una vez.